# How to change a password to an user in apache james

Tags: email, passwords, james

I want to change the password to an specific user of a james server.
Thanks

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect to James Remote Administration Tool via Telnet

```
telnet <ip> 4555
```

The default credentials are login: **root** password: **root**

Once connected, simply run this command:

```
setpassword [username] [password]
```

Answer (score 1):

Better : using the commandline client provided by the project.

It use JMX under the hood. The CLI is packages with every distribution of the server. (you can even execute it via maven from here : https://github.com/apache/james-project/tree/master/server/container/cli)

Then, fnkrm is right, you should go for setpassword.

Alternatively, on 3.0-betax we provide optional admin REST APIs. https://github.com/apache/james-project/tree/master/server/protocols/webadmin . Have a look to the corresponding docker images if interested.

Cheers,

Benoit.